# How do I pick only the first few items in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Here's something simple for someone to answer for me. I've tried searching but I don't know what I'm looking for really.

I have an array from a JSON string, in PHP, of cast and crew members for a movie.

Here I am pulling out only the people with the job name 'Actor'

```
  foreach ($movies[0]->cast as $cast) {
      if ($cast->job == 'Actor') {
    echo '<p><a href="people.php?id=' . $cast->id . '">' . $cast->name . ' - ' . $cast->character . '</a></p>';
      }
  }
```

The problem is, I would like to be able to limit how many people with the job name 'Actor' are pulled out. Say, the first 3.

So how would I pick only the first 3 of these people from this array?

Comment: another option to those below is to add a counter in the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable called `$num_actors` to track how many you've already counted, and `break` out of the loop once you get to 3.

```
$num_actors = 0;
foreach ( $movies[0]->cast as $cast ) {
    if ( $cast->job == 'Actor' ) {
        echo '...';

        $num_actors += 1;
        if ( $num_actors == 3 )
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help. I've picked this one here though because it seemed popular and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

OK - this is a bit of over-kill for this problem, but perhaps it serves some educational purposes. PHP comes with a set of iterators that may be used to abstract iteration over a given set of items.

```
class ActorIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        return $this->current()->job == 'Actor';
    }
}

$maxCount = 3;
$actors   = new LimitIterator(
    new ActorIterator(
        new ArrayIterator($movies[0]->cast)
    ), 
    0, 
    $maxCount
);
foreach ($actors as $actor) {
    echo /*... */;
}
```

By extending the abstract class [`FilterIterator`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) we are able to define a filter that returns only the actors from the given list. [`LimitIterator`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php) allows you to limit the iteration to a given set and the [`ArrayIterator`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) is a simple helper to make native arrays compatible with the [`Iterator`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface. Iterators allow the developer to build chains that define the iteration process which makes them extremely flexible and powerful.

As I said in the introduction: the given problem can be solved easily without this Iterator stuff, but it provides the developer with some extended options and enables code-reuse. You could, for example, enhance the `ActorIterator` to some `CastIterator` that allows you to pass the cast type to filter for in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
$actors=array_filter($movies[0]->cast, function ($v) {
    return $v->job == 'Actor';
});

$first3=array_slice($actors, 0, 3);
```

or even

```
$limit=3;
$actors=array_filter($movies[0]->cast, function ($v) use (&$limit) {
    if ($limit>0 && $v->job == 'Actor') {
         $limit--;
         return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter and an if statement.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($movies[0]->cast as $cast)
{
  if ($cast->job == 'Actor')
  {
    echo '<p><a href="people.php?id=' . $cast->id . '">' . $cast->name . ' - ' . $cast-character . '</a></p>';

    if($count++ >= 3)
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$limit = 3;
$count = 0;

  foreach ($movies[0]->cast as $cast) {
      // You can move the code up here if all you're getting is Actors
      if ($cast->job == 'Actor') {
          if ($count == $limit) break;// stop the loop
          if ($count == $limit) continue;// OR move to next item in loop
          $count++;
          echo '<p><a href="people.php?id=' 
                  . $cast->id 
                  . '">' 
                  . $cast->name 
                  . ' - ' 
                  . $cast->character 
                  . '</a></p>';
      }
  }
```